# Need org.threeten.bp.LocalDate to return date in format "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, yaml, swagger-2.0

I am using `yaml` file to generate classes that will be used to return `JSON` response.

yaml

```
NextPaymentDueDate:
    description: Date the next payment is due on the loan
    type: string
    example: '2018-07-04'
    format: date
```

I am using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to generate these classes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>api-call</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/search.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                <apiPackage>com.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.model</modelPackage>
                <invokerPackage>com.client</invokerPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In my code:

```
  @SerializedName("NextPaymentDueDate")
  private LocalDate nextPaymentDueDate = null;
...
  myObj.setNextPaymentDueDate(LocalDate.parse("2018-07-01"));
```

Result:

```
"nextPaymentDueDate": { <-- note lowercase
            "year": 2018,
            "month": "JULY",
            "era": "CE",
            "dayOfMonth": 1,
            "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
            "dayOfYear": 182,
            "leapYear": false,
            "monthValue": 7,
            "chronology": {
                "id": "ISO",
                "calendarType": "iso8601"
            }
        },
```

I need it to return:

```
"nextPaymentDueDate": {
            "2018-07-01"
        },
```

I also added in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

But this didn't do anything.

Comment: Why are you using ThreeTen if you're using Java 8? ThreeTen is a backport for use by Java 6 and 7. `java8-localdatetime` enables support for Java 8 Time API, not ThreeTen. To support ThreeTen, you need to write and register your own `TypeAdapter` objects.

Comment: @Andreas I wish I have control over what to use :)
I can't seem to override ThreeTen with swager-codegen-plugin :(

Comment: Date/time classes don’t have format of their own, they are simply a container for the amount of time from a specified  anchor point. Instead, you need to use a DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Or in this case the `toString` method, @MadProgrammer, depending on taste. `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` should work just nicely too.

Answer (score 4):

I think is best use the 'java.time.LocalDate'. The `<dateLibrary>` tag in `<configuration>` area needs to be inside a `<configOptions>` tag. See this example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>api-call</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/search.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                   <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
                <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                <apiPackage>com.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.model</modelPackage>
                <invokerPackage>com.client</invokerPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You may want use other parameters. See [this documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin).

And [here](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/) are the Config Options for java language.

Answer (score 1):

Following configuration works for java 11. 'java11-localdatetime' generates 'java.util.Date' instead of 'java.time.LocalDate'. So I had to use 'importMappings' and 'typemappings' to replace 'Date' with 'LocalDate'.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.27</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                    <language>spring</language>                         
                    <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                    <modelPackage>com.xxxx.model</modelPackage>
                    <apiPackage>com.xxxx.generated.api</apiPackage>
                    <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                    <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                    <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                    <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                    <configOptions>
                        <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                        <dateLibrary>java11-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                    </configOptions>
                    <importMappings>
                        <importMapping>Date=java.time.LocalDate</importMapping>
                    </importMappings>
                    <typeMappings>
                        <typeMapping>Date=LocalDate</typeMapping>
                    </typeMappings>
            </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```