# package org.threeten.bp or com.google.gson does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using the codegen maven plugin and the code now generate. And I am using java 8. But I couldn't run

```
maven install
```

due to some missing packages.
This is the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin that I add. This is fine to build the jar.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.26</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>./generated-sources/</sourceFolder>
                        <java8>true</java8>
                        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    </configOptions>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/</output>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>./src/main/resources/api-contract/first.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <configOptions>
                                <apiPackage>com.service.api</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>com.service.model</modelPackage>
                                <invokerPackage>com.service.handler</invokerPackage>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Yet, if I change the language to

```
                            <language>java</language>
```

and run maven install. the code can still be downloaded but compile error pops up

```
package com.google.gson does not exist
```

In addition, if I change the language to

```
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>restemplate</library>
```

and run maven install. the code can still be downloaded as well but this time, another compile error pops up

```
package org.threeten.bp does not exist
package com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.threetenbp does not exist
```

As I am only trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQaFKGU8oi4 but I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

Comment: You need to add the dependencies for gson and bp.

Comment: See this thread. It seem to have gotten it figured out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544854/need-org-threeten-bp-localdate-to-return-date-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd